# Override Bundle and layout in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am creating a page in yii2 project
I want to change layout for that page 
How can i do that?
I did create new layout in `layouts` folder
and also created new `bundle` and registered on the `view` page like this

```
MobileAsset::register($this);

<div class="container">
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">12</span> New</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">5</span> Deleted</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">3</span> Warnings</li>
</ul>
```

But it still uses the default layout `layout/main.php` 
It uses both bundle on that file
What can i do to tell view file to only use `MobileAsset` and not the `AppAsset` for this page
So what am i doing wrong here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the layout in whole controller :

```
Class SiteController extends Controller
{
    Public $layout ="abc";
    .......
}
```

To change on selected action only:

```
Public function actionTest() {
    $this->layout ="abc";
}
```

[reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#layouts)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `$this->layout = 'layout_name';` in controller file.
So, code like,

```
public function actionName()
{
    $this->layout = 'layout_name';
    .......
    ...
}
```